# How to completely delete files in Android so they can't be recovered by tools?

Tags: android

How can we completely delete files in Android? 
For Android, the ROM is exFAT, sdcard has FAT32/ext3, ext4 file format.

I want to remove a selected file completely, so you can not recover it. Do you know of a solution?

Comment: The file system is the least of your worries.  Most devices are flash based so even overwriting the data won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not even going to ask why you want to do this.

Simply writing zeros over top of the file before deleting it should be considered "good enough".

From there, you are going to have to do some serious filesystem manipulation to try and write data on top of the area where the file was previously located. With a large flash device, we could be talking several Gigabytes before the previous content is permanently destroyed.

Comment: For the special security requirements, we should remove it totally. I worry that file name can be found.  Another question, how can I found deleted file (by normal method) and recovery it?

Comment: If security is a real concern, then I recommend not writing to flash. If you read up on flash "wear leveling" you'll see why I suggest this.

Comment: You mean the file in flash can't be removed completely?

Comment: Bits in flash can only be programmed from 1 to 0. To go the other way, they have to be *erased*. To prevent from burning out the same cells in flash, the support hardware will skip the "delete" part, and just write to somewhere else on the chip, until that space is needed. With the right tools, one could read back the raw contents of the chip, and find what was left behind.

Answer (score 0):

As SD-card is used under the file system, there is no guarantee, that you will have no pieces of the file. At least, I think that it is possible, that SD card will function like SSD disk: it can move sectors transparently for you. But there is a try :)

You can delete the file you want, then create a file which will fill all the space available on sd-card, and fill that file by zeros. Then you can delete that file too.

Answer (score 0):

It's really old question but if someone is getting redirected here then please use following apps

Secure Delete: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.peterhohsy.securedelete

or

Secure Wipe: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pinellascodeworks.securewipe

depending on your requirement